# 'Bulk insert' for cascaded list

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an object with a cascaded list which is mapped in the following way:

```
HasMany(x => x.Products).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan(); //.BatchSize(10000);
```

After adding 20000 products to the list, the commit takes more then 30 seconds (while it should be max 3 seconds).

What I need is a kind of bulk insert. I could follow this approach: [Speed up bulk insert operations with NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943967/speed-up-bulk-insert-operations-with-nhibernate). I know this solution uses the `StatelessSession` but anyway, my hope is to configure these things in my mapping, adding objects directly to the list in my `Entity` and `NHibernate` takes care of the remaining stuff. Setting the `BatchSize` on the mapping of the list seems to has no effect.

Is there any way to accomplish this task in an acceptable time?

Comment: bulk insert is not something that you need for every entity.. whenever I need it, i have created a separate extension method on stateless session `bulkInsert` which I use for this purpose

Comment: This is what I feared. But hope dies last :-)

Comment: if you read blogs from ayande,,, he states the same thing :0 bulk insert is not job of ORM, for that you would need specialized tools, so dont expect much from any ORM when it comes to bulk copy/upload

Answer (score 0):

I think that batch size in the mapping is only related to fetching.  You can try using this configuration in your nhibernate config:

```
<property name="adonet.batch_size">250</property>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfotunately this option seems to has no effect. The commit still takes more than 30s.

Answer (score 0):

the only to speed things up is use stateless session

(read this: [Inserts of stateless session of NHibernate are slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563108/inserts-of-stateless-session-of-nhibernate-are-slow))

also, take care of below - to make it even more faster

> cfg.AutoCommentSql = false;
>
> cfg.LogFormattedSql = false;